# Alternative to PyGaze (Tobii 4C)

Tags: python, eye-tracking

I used to work with an eye tracker Tobii Pro and wrote a **Python script** using **PyGaze**. I recently had to change of tracker and got a **Tobii 4C**, which doesn't seem to work with that PyGaze library.

I've searched the internet for hours but I couldn't find an **alternative** to PyGaze. Do you know some library/API/... that I can use ? *(Python is not an obligation)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at Psychopy (http://www.psychopy.org/). It has support for some Tobii devices, although I am not sure if there is support for Tobii 4C.

Comment: PyGaze is using PsychoPy and I already searched that way. I think it has to do because of the license but I'm not sure. (Anyway, for me it is too late to solve that problem :/)

Answer (score 2):

You can see the various available SDKs for their products [on their website](https://developer.tobii.com/tobii-sdk-guide/). Apparently you have no less than three of them:

- The [Core SDK](https://developer.tobii.com/tobii-core-sdk/), for general interactive use, mainly in C#, although it offers a lower-level API in C# and C/C++.
- The [Gaming SDK](https://developer.tobii.com/tobii-unity-sdk/) supporting Unity, in C#.
- The [Pro SDK](https://developer.tobii.com/tobii-pro-sdk/) for analytical applications, in C, Python, Matlab and .Net Framework.

Note that licensing of the SDKs vary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already have the SDKs but those give me raw data. I was more looking for a similar to PyGaze library that can at least detect fixations from those data.

Comment: @Shamrock Seems that the Core SDK can do that, see [`FixationDataStream`](https://tobii.github.io/CoreSDK/api/Tobii.Interaction.FixationDataStream.html) and [sample code](https://github.com/Tobii/CoreSDK/blob/master/samples/Streams/Interaction_Streams_102/Program.cs).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to investigate that way.