# Tobii Eye Tracker

Tags: python, nvidia

We are trying to connect our Tobii Eye Tracker to our Ubuntu OS 16.04.6 LTS Nvidia Jetson TX2 module. However, when we want to pip install tobii_research we keep getting an error that says that there are not matching distributions found for it. Has anyone had any success doing this? We are using a virtual environment for python 3.5 and we are trying to install psychopy but it keeps saying that it is failing with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-cdg_if0d/psychopy. Do we need psychopy inorder to do the pip install tobii_research?

We also have a library that is called "tobiiresearch" and it has a .py file with the function we need which is `fr = find_all_eyetrackers()`, but when calling that in python it says that it cannot be found.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems that you are having the same issue I had in the past. The solution is just to change from `tobii_research` to `tobii-research`. But as I see, you also need some support. I just answer you below.

Comment: Hi @FranciscoMariaCalisto, i just noticed that the tobii eye tracker deals with drivers of x86 architecture whereas my NVidia Jetson TX2 has an arm processor. Do you think this is an issue? I believe we are unable to port the sdk drivers over for that reason. A professional told us to develop an ROS wrapper for our system. As for Tobii support, we contacted them and are waiting for a reply from their technical team as I believe they may have drivers for an ARM architecture available. But so far we have not gotten a response.

Comment: Indeed, this might be a good question to make on this community platform. To answer your question, I believe that those drivers have a small relation with the SDK limitations. While it is compatible with Operation System (OS). When you say, to develop across the ROS wrapper it is another abstraction level for the communication between what you need and the Tobii Eye Tracker. Nothing related to your needs. It was just a good external recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You need the python version to be 3.10.x.
Faced the same problem and I used this to solve the problem.

Cheers,
Xin

Answer (score 0):

Try to do instead:

```
pip install tobii-research
```

As you mentioned, the [Tobii Pro SDK](http://developer.tobiipro.com/) lets you interact easily with your eye tracker and write your own research applications for collecting and analyzing eye tracking data. I recommend you to contact the [Tobii Pro Support](http://www.tobiipro.com/contact/contact-support/) directly, as stated in an [early post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011362/alternative-to-pygaze-tobii-4c/55170315#55170315). You have also the [forum](https://developer.tobii.com/community/forums/topic/tobii-pro-sdk-gaze-coordinates/), they are fast to answer you.